# disable direct linking to my files from the user's browser

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

I'm using the following `.htaccess` configurations to disable hotlinking :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)mywesbite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(flv|mp4|pdf|xls|doc|mov|wmv|avi)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/images/logo.jpg [R,L]
```

And I've tested it and everything is working fine, and now I want to disable downloading the files when the user tries to add the direct link of one of the files to his browser's address bar. **Only** the users that are referred to the file from my website can download it. Is there any way I can get that done by adding some more `.htaccess` configurations?

Comment: I would just like to point out that this does not provide any real security. There are many easy ways to defeat this type of protection, for one example see the [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) Firefox add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mywebsite.com(/)?.*$     [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(flv|mp4|pdf|xls|doc|mov|wmv|avi)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/images/logo.jpg [R,NC]
```

Alternative if that doesnt work

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mywebsite.com(/)?.*$     [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(flv|mp4|pdf|xls|doc|mov|wmv|avi)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/images/logo.jpg [R,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! it's working but I can't view the files from my website using Firefox, Chrome is working fine though. I wonder what could be going wrong?

Comment: Certain browsers don't use referrer information at all, that would be the downside is that they won't be able to view your website, and naturally a small percentage of people will be in the dark. I don't think firefox is one of those browsers, but make sure you don't have a hide-referrer plugin installed or something.